# How do you install an engine for JavaScriptEngineSwitcher?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to run some javascript from a .NET class library using JSPool and JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8, but I can't work out how to install JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8. My code so far is simple

```cs
public class Renderer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly JsPool _pool;
    private static readonly string[] _requiredFiles = { "vendors", "app" };

    public Renderer(string jsPath)
    {
        _pool = new JsPool(new JsPoolConfig
        {
            Initializer = initEngine =>
            {
                foreach (var file in _requiredFiles)
                {
                    initEngine.ExecuteFile(jsPath + "\\" + file + ".js");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public string Render()
    {
        using (var engine = _pool.GetEngine())
        {
            return engine.Evaluate<string>(@"myjsFn()");
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _pool.Dispose();
    }
}
```

But this throws a NullRefException as no  engine has been registered

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core.JsEngineSwitcher.CreateDefaultJsEngineInstance()
```

My app is targeting dnx451, and I've specified JSPool 0.4.1 and JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8 1.5.8 in my dependencies. I've had a good look but can't seem to find anything that shows any code required to register the V8 engine. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Never again use DNX. It has no meaning right now. Say .NET Framework or .NET Core.

Comment: FYI, take a look at the dispose method of the object returned by the pool's `GetEngine()` method.  Contrary to what you'd expect, IIRC, it *doesn't* return the engine back to the pool.  There's a separate method you call on the pool.

Comment: @Lex Li The reason I said DNX is because the app is written using the RC1, I've not had a chance yet to upgrade it!

Comment: Thanks @Amy I'll double check that

Comment: @JordanWallwork RC1 is the test bits of last November, and all kinds of issues are expected right now. Do upgrade it or it would be difficult for others to help.

Comment: @JordanWallwork JavaScript Engine Switcher version 1.X does not support .NET and ASP.NET Core. Support of these frameworks will be added in [version 2.0](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/tree/2.0).

Comment: Can I suggest you, @Jordan Wallwork, to change the name of your class? Renderer does not make sense: it's not related to graphics or something that requires a rendering process, it's an Evaluator, Runtime or Compiler, and so on...

Answer (score 2):

This problem was solved in the [JavaScript Engine Switcher version 2.0.0](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/releases/tag/v2.0.0) and [JSPool version 2.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JSPool/2.0.0). Before installing of NuGet packages, I recommend to first read [“How to upgrade applications to version 2.X”](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/How-to-upgrade-applications-to-version-2.X) section of the documentation.

But worth noting, that the [JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8/) module can be used only in  web application created by the “ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)” template.

Comment: Hi. Do you know any documentation/starter kit for JavaScriptEngineSwitcher? The documentation on their git hub wiki is very poor, and I couldn't find any starter kit either

Comment: Ashkan Sirous, until there is no other source of documentation, but I will gradually write the documentation on GitHub. This is due to the fact, that for a long time, [JavaScript Engine Switcher](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher) was an auxiliary library for the [Bundle Transformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/). Then came the [React.NET](https://github.com/reactjs/React.NET), and the JavaScript Engine Switcher began to gain popularity.

Comment: Great :) please also share the link for me. I really need it.

Comment: I am also setting up a project now, so it would be a great help if you can share some code, or a sample project with me

Comment: https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/tree/master/samples - sample projects

Comment: Thanks a lot  Andrey. :)

Comment: any news about documentation? :) I've downloaded your link and tried to work with it, but as far as I understand, the purpose of the sample was to evaluate a javascript code.

Comment: I wonder if you have a sample that can help me build my structure based on your library

Comment: Documentation will be published gradually at the following address - https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki. You can also see [unit tests](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/tree/master/test) or [source code of the Bundle Transformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest).